# Overlay a background-image with an rgba color, with a CSS3 transition

Tags: css, overlay, background-image, css-transitions

Earlier today I asked [Overlay a background-image with an rgba background-color](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17134929/1544337). My goal is to have a div with a background-image, and when someone hovers the div, the background-image gets overlayed with an rgba color. In [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17134984/1544337), a solution with `:after` was given:

```css
#the-div {
    background-image: url('some-url');
}

#the-div:hover:after {
    content: ' ';
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}
```

I now would like to have the same, but with a CSS transition: I'd like the background color to fade in. I tried adding `transition: all 1s;` to the `#the-div` CSS, but that didn't work. I also try to add it to `#the-div:hover` and `#the-div:after`, but that didn't work either.

Is there a pure CSS way to add a fading in overlay to a div with a background-image?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

## [*demo*](http://codepen.io/thebabydino/pen/AtzpB)

```
.boo {
  position: relative;
  width: 20em; min-height: 10em;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0) url(http://placekitten.com/320/160);
  transition: background-color 1s;
}
.boo:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}
.boo:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
  background-color: inherit;
  content: ' ';
}
```

#### What am I doing here?

What I am doing here is that I am setting a RGBa `background-color` on the `div`, behind its `background-image` and transitioning this `background-color` (its alpha) on `:hover`. All this happens *behind* the `background-image`. However, I am also using `background-color: inherit` on the pseudo-element, which means that, at any given moment, the pseudo-element, which is situated above its parent `div` (and therefore above the `background-image` of the `div`) is going to have the same `background-color` (meaning that the `background-color` of the pseudo-element is going to transition from `rgba(0,0,0,0)` to `rgba(0,0,0,.5)` on `:hover`).

---

#### Why do it this way?

The reason why I am not transitioning directly the `background-color` of the pseudo-element is that support for transitions on pseudo-elements is still not that good yet.

#### Support for transitions on pseudo-elements

**✓ Firefox** supports transitions on pseudo-elements and has supported them for quite a while, let's get this out of the way first.

**✗** Current versions of **Safari** and **Opera** don't support transitions on pseudo-elements.

**Chrome** supports transitions on pseudo-elements only starting from version 26.

**IE10** supports them in a bit of a weird way, meaning that something like:

```
.boo:before { color: blue; transition: 1s; }
.boo:hover:before { color: red; }
```

won't work, you have to specify the hover state on the element itself as well. Like this:

```
.boo:hover {}
.boo:before { color: blue; transition: 1s; }
.boo:hover:before { color: red; }
```

---

More info and examples about how you can transition various properties of pseudo-elements using this `inherit` technique: http://vimeo.com/51897358

---

## **EDIT**

Transitions directly on pseudo-elements are now supported in Opera since the switch to Blink and in Safari since 6.1.

Comment: That's quite an ingenious solution! I suggest specifying the transition property so that the element is not animated on page load: `transition: background-color 1s;`.

Comment: True. Added the transitioned property name.

Comment: I'm glad to see that there still are people on SO that provide explanation on their code :) good practice, keep up the good work!

Comment: @lolmaus I'll probably do that, but perhaps others have even better answers :)

Answer (score 5):

Allthough @Ana technique is also nice, and works fine, allow me to slightly alter my answer to the [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17135830/overlay-a-background-image-with-an-rgba-color-with-a-css3-transition), and add the transition in that code.
http://jsfiddle.net/Pevara/N2U6B/2/

```
#the-div {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    background: url(http://placekitten.com/500/500) no-repeat center center;
    position: relative;
}

#the-div:after {
    content: ' ';
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    transition: background-color .5s;
}
#the-div:hover:after {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);   
}
```

What I did is i defined the `:after` pseudo element on the default state of the div in stead of only on the hover state, but with a fully transparent background, and a transition on the background color. On hover of the div, I change the background color of the pseudo element to be less transparent. Thanks to the transition it fades in nicely.

The technique is basicly the same as what @Ana did, but perhaps a bit more intuitive because I don't use the `background-color: inherit;`. Also if the div would becomes bigger then the background image, you would not get the 'double darkness' on the edges, as demonstrated here http://codepen.io/anon/pen/cjoHr versus here http://jsfiddle.net/Pevara/N2U6B/3/

Comment: True, this is more straightforward. The only problem is support. It's only going to work in Firefox and Chrome 26+. I've edited my answer to include info about support.

Comment: @ana as Chrome user I was not aware of that restriction in most browsers. Some day... Thanks for teaching me something new, and +1 to you!