# css3 filter with arbitrary color

Tags: css

I will give an example: Consider you have a `div` with an image for a background, you hover over it and some colour is added to the image, much like a filter, however it is a single colour (transparent as well so you can still see the original image. The filters in css3, atleast these which I have seen ( http://html5-demos.appspot.com/static/css/filters/index.html ) do not offer single color manipulation. Is such a thing achievable?

Things I have considered adding an element on top of the `div` (z index) and have a transparent background with some color appear on it when it is hovered on, but I wonder if it is possible with css3.

Comment: Im a noob so if wrong sorry. But could you not use rgba (0, 255, 0, 0.3) for the hover effect on the div. with the 0.3 being the opacity?

Comment: if so then see this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17134929/overlay-a-background-image-with-an-rgba-background-color

Comment: This does what I ask for to some extent. The problem is that it replaces the background image. It doesn't enhance it. It is a start, though.

Comment: On the JSfiddle in that link it doesn't replace the image it overlays the color with an opacity that you define. Like in the cat here http://jsfiddle.net/Pevara/N2U6B/

Comment: I see. If you want, you can make an answer to this question, so I can approve it and we can close it with status 'solved'

Comment: will do :) glad its sorted

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```css
#the-div {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    background: url(http://placekitten.com/500/500) no-repeat center center;
    position: relative;
}
#the-div:hover:after {
    content: ' ';
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}
```

See it in jsFiddle.