# CSS background image & div style color filter

Tags: html, css, dynamic, colors, styles

I am using an image background using css :

```
tbody 
{
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url("http://pattern.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 800px;
}
```

and in the HTML file I am trying to add a style in this div (tbody). The style will be an overlay color filter. The reason I want to add this in the HTML and not the CSS is that it is going to be dynamic.

The RGB of the filter will be like that :

```
<tbody style="background-color: rgb( {Query.Visits_Color_R},{Query.Visits_Color_G},{Query.Visits_Color_B},0.5);">
```

I guess I have to use something similar to `-webkit-filter:`

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: @MoshFeu The problem is that I cannot make it work using the webkit filter. What is the way to change the color? I want the background image from the css to show up. It will just have a filter (in the div) on top that will make it look with a different color.

Comment: Answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17134929/overlay-a-background-image-with-an-rgba-background-color

Comment: @IsrwLuke I want to have the filter in the HTML and not the CSS. It is going to be dynamic using the {Query.Colors}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

- If you want alpha to be affected you want to use rgba() not rgb().
- Inline styles override linked styles in a stylesheet. Add your background image into your inline style e.g.

Your top-most layer should be at the front See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Background_and_Borders/Using_CSS_multiple_backgrounds